# append elements satisfy certain condition to list in swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

I would like to append all elements that satisfy some predicate to an empty list. I did something like this:

```
fact(a).
fact(b).
fact(c).
append(list, E, R) :- fact(E),append([], [E], R).
```

but it didn't work.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append/3 is a predefined predicate, you are not allowed to redefine it yourself.
I think you want to have a list R of all facts. So, here is my suggestion:

```
main(ListOfFacts) :-
    bagof(Afact, fact(Afact) , ListOfFacts).

?- main(R).
R = [a,b,c].
```

Bagof/3 is a predefined predicate where argument 3 is a list of all values defined of argument 1, which succeeds in the predicate in argument 2.

Did it help ?

Comment: Yes, it certainly helped. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, just a follow-up question (not exactly related to the original question): how can I use the output of 'main(R).' as an input argument of another function, say I want to append R to another list to form a nested list? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a one liner, say calling append: main(Rs), append(Rs, SomethingElse, FinalResult).

Comment: Yes, it worked. But I wonder if it is possible to call main() implicitly within the second function, something analogous to this if done in Python: def append_list(SomethingElse); R=main(); SomethingElse.append(Rs); return SomethingElse.   So the second function automatically calls main() without the command being explicitly typed by the user.

Comment: I tried something like this and it worked: main_two(FinalResult):- main(R), append(Rs, SomethingElse, FinalResult). Please feel free to comment on this solution and thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yes, its "information hiding" to make main_two more simple for its users/callers if the intermediate SomethinElse is not needed. So now you know all about Prolog !